# Nvidia low res after update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

Last night I did an standard Ubuntu update and somehow this has disable my nvidia drivers and the screen resolution is super low. How can I get my resolution back?  I have an RTX 2070 card and don't care whether I use the actual nvidia drivers or now, but at my original install was unsuccessful figuring out how to use distribution drivers.  I installed the nvidia drivers from their web site.

So I have two questions.  How can I get my resolution back, and how do I prevent this from being a recurring problem?

Comment: How did you install Nvidia drivers? Installing "from the site" will have this problem after each kernel upgrade.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: 18.10 ubuntu.  I installed using the .run file from nvidia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your resolution back by booting with the previous kernel using `grub` menu.

Installation from a downloaded `.run` file is wrong. It requires reinstallation of the drivers after each kernel upgrade.

The recommended way is to install drivers from Ubuntu repositories. If there is no suitable driver for your card there, you can install them from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Now you need to uninstall the driver you have by running the same `.run` file with `--uninstall` at the end.

Then you can install drivers by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
```

Comment: When you say to install from Ubuntu repos, do you mean using "ubuntu-drivers devices" followed by "ubuntu-drivers autoinstall", as described here? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux  And, any reason not to do that over top of what I have going now?

Comment: You need to uninstall the drivers by running the same script with `--uninstall` at the end. Then add the PPA as described there and install the 410 or 415 driver. Autoinstall is no good because the driver is too new.

Comment: I'm part way through, it recommends 418.  Do you know something they don't know?

Comment: It looks like the latest are 418, so why not. `415` was an example. It can be 410,415, or 418 for your card.